# How make TikZ arrow tips match tips of newtxmath font's arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows

In equations (2) and (3), both of which use TikZ, how do I get the arrow tips to be the same as those produced as in equation (1) by the math font in use?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 2
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r]{$f$} & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 3
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      middlearrow/.style 2 args={
          thick,
          decoration={
              markings, 
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}, \node[#1]{#2};}
          },
          postaction={decorate}
      },
  ]
  \draw[middlearrow={below}{$\sigma$}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[thick,->=-latex] (0, -1) -- (2, -1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[![Want TikZ arrow tips to match tips of math font's arrows][1]][1]

*Note:* I am *not* asking the reverse question! That is, I am *not* asking how to modify the arrows produced by `\rightarrow`, etc., to match those produced by TikZ.

**Addition:** I have the same question — just about matching the arrow heads, not about the syntax — but for using TeX Gyre Termes Math font (with XeLaTeX) instead of newtxmath.  See: [How make TikZ arrow tips match arrows with TeX Gyre Termes Math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565131/13492)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfm2P.png

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Please tell me the exact syntax for specifying that arrow style in each of the two arrows created for equation (3). [For the 2nd arrow of that, I tried `\draw[thick,->=-Straight Barb] (0, -1) -- (2, -1);` but get no change! And I haven't a clue to the correct syntax to get it in the `middlearrow` construction.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set in the preamble:

```latex
\tikzset{>=Straight Barb, commutative diagrams/arrow style=tikz}
```

you say to Ti*k*Z which arrows to use by default, and to `tikz-cd` to follow that decision.

You then remove all *specific* diagram styles and  you obtain this:

[image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\tikzset{>=Straight Barb, commutative diagrams/arrow style=tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 2
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r]{$f$} & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 3
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      middlearrow/.style 2 args={
          thick,
          decoration={
              markings, 
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}, \node[#1]{#2};}
          },
          postaction={decorate}
      },
  ]
  \draw[middlearrow={below}{$\sigma$}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[thick,->] (0, -1) -- (2, -1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answered *all* my questions about the matter, thank you! You forgot to include the `\tikzset` command in the code you show. Also, the `=-latex` phrase should now be omitted from the final `\draw` once the globael `\tikzset` command has been included.

Comment: Pasted wrong buffer ;-) --- now it's ok

Comment: Probably you should apply @Zarko idea too to use `[scale=0.8]` to match sizes...

Comment: Yes, `[scale=0.8]`

Answer (score 4):

it seems that to `rightarrow` using `,newtxmath` package is `Straight Barb` arrows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}    % eq 2
\tikzcdset{
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}}
          }
  \begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r]{$f$} & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 3
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
      middlearrow/.style 2 args={
          thick,
          decoration={
              markings,
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}, \node[#1]{#2};}
          },
          postaction={decorate}
      },
  ]
  \draw[middlearrow={below}{$\sigma$}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[thick,->] (0, -1) -- (2, -1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Tipe of arrows head you can set globaly by placing `tikzset` and `\tikzcdset` in document preamble. Foe example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}}% if you not bear that 
                                      % arrows head hasn't equal size as in math,
                                      % just remove `scale` option
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}}
          }

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}    % eq 2
  \begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r]{$f$} & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 3
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      middlearrow/.style 2 args={
          thick,
          decoration={
              markings,
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}, \node[#1]{#2};}
          },
          postaction={decorate}
      },
  ]
  \draw[middlearrow={below}{$\sigma$}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[thick,->] (0, -1) -- (2, -1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

**Note:**
Let me emphasize, that this solution gives desired result if you use `newtxmath` fonts. At other math fonts, for example `lmodern` you should use `Computer Modern Rightarrow[]` or simple `>`.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. And I see how to put the `\tikzset` command outside the particular `equation` environment, so it will affect all `tikzcd` figures. But how can I similarly make the specification of `Straight Barb` to affect *all* `tikzpicture` environments?

Comment: You can set arrows heads tip globally, see edited answer. Also see @Rmano answer.