# How make TikZ arrow tips match arrows with TeX Gyre Termes Math font?

Tags: tikz-arrows

How can I (globally in the document, I hope) change the shape of TikZ arrowheads (including those in `tikzcd` environments) so match the arrowheads from the TeX Gyre Terms Math font (using XeLaTeX)?

The style `Straight Barb` *almost* matches, but the ends of the barbs are different: in TeX Gyre Termes Math, the ends of the barbs are horizontal, whereas in TikZ `Straight Barb` heads, the ends of the bars are perpendicular to the body of the barb.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5in,right=2.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  >={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
  commutative diagrams/arrow style=tikz
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

\large
\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 2
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r,thick] {$f$} & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Different barb end angles, TikZ and TeX Gyre Termes Math]

**Related:** [How make TikZ arrow tips match tips of newtxmath font's arrows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565112/13492)

Comment: Please check *TikZ & PGF manual, section Reference: Arrow Tips* to see which arrows heads are available. If no one march your wish, ask some one (the best the author of `arrows.meta` library ) to design new arrows head.

Comment: @Zarko: I had already looked in the manual section you cite to see if this kind of arrow tip was available, but I did not see it there. Is the author of `arrows.meta` somebody other than TillTantau? Contact info? (I don't see any in `pgfmanual.pdf` or `pgfllibraryarrows.meta.code.tex`)

Comment: It seems that the author is Till Tantau.

Comment: Maybe the `math font` option of tikz-cd is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Symbol1: Yes, that seems to do exactly what I want. (I know from the tikzcd manual that there can be issues with math font tips fitting onto arrow shanks, but I haven't found any so far with TeX Gyre Termes Math.)

Comment: @Symbol1: Please make our comment an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *official* solution is the `math font` option of tikz-cd.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}


\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style={math font}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{\begingroup\pgfmathreturn.25em\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{rule_thickness}{0}{\begingroup\pgfmathreturn.06em\endgroup}
% credit to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420034/tikzcdsetarrow-style-math-font-breaks-the-rendering-of-arrows

\begin{document}

\large
\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 2
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r] {$f$} & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}


\makeatletter
% based on the definition of arrow tip "Straight Barb"
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = TeX Gyre Termes Math,
  defaults = {
    %%% <<< begin of change
    length = +3.5pt 2,
    %%% <<< end of change
    width'  = +0pt 2,
    line width = +0pt 1 1,
  },
  setup code = {
    % Compute front miter length:
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfarrowlength}{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \let\pgf@temp@quot\pgfmathresult%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult pt%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@x%
    \pgf@x4\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@x by1pt%
    \pgfmathsqrt@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
    \pgf@xc\pgfmathresult\pgfarrowlinewidth% xc is front miter
    \pgf@xc.5\pgf@xc
    \pgf@xa\pgf@temp@quot\pgfarrowlinewidth% xa is extra harpoon miter
    % Set ends
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin
      \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \else
      \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc\ifpgfarrowharpoon\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa\fi}
    \fi
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    % harpoon miter correction
    \ifpgfarrowreversed
      \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgfarrowlength\ifpgfarrowharpoon\advance\pgf@x by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth\fi}
    \else
      \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \fi
    % The hull:
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin
      \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{\ifpgfarrowharpoon-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth\else0pt\fi}%
    \else%
      \ifpgfarrowharpoon
        \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa}{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}%
      \else
        \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa}{0pt}%
      \fi%
    \fi
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{.5\pgfarrowwidth\advance\pgf@y by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{.5\pgfarrowwidth\advance\pgf@y by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}%
    \ifpgfarrowharpoon
      \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}%
    \fi
    % The following are needed in the code:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlinewidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowwidth
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin\pgfsetroundjoin\else\pgfsetmiterjoin\fi
    \ifpgfarrowroundcap\pgfsetroundcap\else\pgfsetbuttcap\fi
    \ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth\else\pgfsetlinewidth{+\pgfarrowlinewidth}\fi
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgfarrowwidth}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \ifpgfarrowharpoon
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by\ifpgfarrowreversed\else-\fi\pgfarrowlinewidth}{0pt}}
    \else
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-.5\pgfarrowwidth}}
    \fi
    \pgfusepathqstroke
    %%% <<< begin of change
    % draw two white lines
    \begin{pgfscope}
      % \pgfsetstrokecolor{red}\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.5} % just for test
      \pgfsetstrokecolor{white}
      \pgfmathsincos{atan2(2*\pgfarrowlength,\pgfarrowwidth)}
      \pgfmathreciprocal{\pgfmathresulty}
      \pgf@xa=\pgfmathresult\pgflinewidth
      \pgf@ya=\pgfmathresultx pt
      \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@ya
      \pgf@ya=\dimexpr.5\pgfarrowwidth-\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@ya\pgflinewidth+.5\pgflinewidth\relax
      % let w = arrow width, l = arrow length, x = line width, 
      % and tan(.) = w/(2l)
      % top line = (-sin(.) * x/2, w/2 + (1-cos(.)) * x/2) -- +(sin(.) * x/2, 0pt),
      %   where -x/2 < -sin(.) * x/2 < 0
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{\pgf@ya}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
      \ifpgfarrowharpoon
      \else
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{-\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
      \fi
      \pgfusepathqstroke
    \end{pgfscope}
    %%% <<< end of change
  },
  parameters = {
    \the\pgfarrowlinewidth,%
    \the\pgfarrowlength,%
    \the\pgfarrowwidth,%
    \ifpgfarrowharpoon h\fi%
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin j\fi%
    \ifpgfarrowroundcap c\fi%
  },
}
\makeatother


\tikzset{
  >={TeX Gyre Termes Math[scale=.8]}
}

\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  every arrow/.append style={line width=1.2pt}
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{equation}    % eq 1
  A \longrightarrow B \rightarrow C
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}    % eq 2
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r, "f"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm getting much better results by using just `\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}`, as suggested in a comment to my original post. In parrticular, your arrow heads appear to me as considerably larger than the ones in ordinary math.

Comment: @murray I think in figure 1, the size of arrow head is ok.

Comment: You're right, the size is OK. I was still using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, which does make the arrow head too large. Which suggests your solution is not as robust as the one suggested in the comment made to use `math font`.

Comment: @murray Yes, you are right.